# PDF/Print/E-mail icons in custom component in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to add PDF/Print/E-mail icon to my component. The problem is I don't know how.. I search google, found nice articles and discussions, but still can't figure out - What, Where and How to integrate that this functionality would work withing my custom component.

If anyone has any ideas, where to start from, which files I need to include and where, please tell me :)

I'd really appreciate :)

maybe there's some articles or book that in details explains the process (step by step)

Comment: [This](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=304&t=321893) thread on Joomla forum might help. P.S. I'm not sure this question is in line with the "[What kind of questions can I ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)" FAQ.

Comment: I have seen this thread.. but it didn't help... I think there has to be somewhere an article that explains in details, or maybe someone know here :)

Comment: In articles by default these icons are present unless you deselect then in Article attributes in the admin panel.

Comment: it's not an article, it's a custom component :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this problem.

It might not be the best solution but for a fast solution it works fine.

PDF - generate the link in view - tmpl - default.php make link `<a href="">PDF</a>`
  index.php?option="smth"&view="smth"..... and at the end add &format=pdf
  in your view folder copy view.html.php  and rename it to view.pdf.php - and your set to go!

Print - the very same thing as PDF at the end of link put &format=print and create view.print.php

Email - you can directly address the com_mailto component - here's the link example

```
index.php?option=com_mailto&tmpl=component&link="your page link you want to be sent"
```

So this is your fastest solution of the problem.